# How to check input string being a fixed format by regular expression

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a program to store family members data.

input format like below,

```
Country Husband wife child pet
```

example input

```
Japan ken Annie may money
```

input the Area ,husband ,wife,child and pet's name, and split by space,
I want to check that user input is right or not.
I tried

```
( /^(.+)(\s(.+)){4}$/ ) ? print "good" : print "fail";
```

But it can only judge whether more than 5 words are entered instead of judging exactly five.
Like, if input

```
Japan ken Annie may money hank queen
```

will still pass the judgmental.

Please tell me where I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Use `\S` instead of `\.` to describe the non-whitespace parts: `/^(\S+)(?:\s(\S+)){4}$/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the string `Japan ken Annie may money hank queen`, your first `(.+)` is matching `Japan ken Annie` so the rest of the regular expression is able to match the four extra names without problems and matches.

The problem is that dot `.` matches also spaces.

A common solution for words separated by spaces (or any other delimier) is to use this expression:

```
^ something (?: separator something )quantifier $ # Note: don't take into account spaces

 (where 'something' cannot contain the separator)
```

So in your case you could write:

```
^\S+(?:\s+\S+){4}$
```

Where `\S+` means : Any non whitespace character, 1 or more times

Please, note that `\s` matches any whitespace character (including new lines) So if you are reading the file as a whole (instead of line by line) it is advised to use `\h` instead (which matches *horizontal* whitespace characters)

```
^\S+(?:\h+\S+){4}$
```

If you use `\s` and you don't process the content line by line, your regular expression may try to match data accross several lines, which is wrong for your case.

Also, if you are reading the file as a whole, you may also need to use the `m` modifier

```
/^\S+(?:\h+\S+){4}$/m
```

or

```
(?m)^\S+(?:\h+\S+){4}$
```

So that `^` and `$` match the begin and end of line (instead of being and end of string)

Consider using non-capturing groups `(?:)` If you don't plan to capture data.

If you plan to capture all data of the line, you may use this regex instead:

```
^(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)\h+(\S+)$
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a good library to read input.<sup>†</sup>  The [Getopt::Long](https://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt::Long) is excellent and practically a standard

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Getopt::Long;
use List::Util qw(any);

my ($country, $husband, $wife, $child, $pet);

GetOptions( 
    'country=s'   => \$country,  
    'husband=s'   => \$husband, 
    'wife=s'      => \$wife, 
    'child|kid=s' => \$child,
    'pet=s'       => \$pet
);

# If they all must be submitted, and no other input, check
usage() if any { not defined $_ } $country, $husband, $wife, $child, $pet;
usage() if @ARGV;

say "Family of $wife and $husband come from $country";

sub usage {
    say STDERR "
Usage: $0 ...

All listed arguments are mandatory.

No other input is supported.
";

    exit;
}
```

An option value with multiple words is supplied under quotes.  I show above how to set up alternate names for input options, they can be shortened as long as unambiguous, one hyphen can be dropped, etc.

```
program.pl --husband Ken -w "Jo Ann" -kid May
```

Please see documentation for far more features in library's use.

Options submitted to a Perl program on the command line are placed in `@ARGV` [predefined variable](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar). As the library parses the input it recognizes in `@ARGV` it removes those elements from it, and after it's done  `@ARGV` remains with unnamed options (those that don't start with `-` nor directly follow one such).  This allows us to pass yet other input, most often filenames, which we can then use directly out of `@ARGV`. (Otherwise they are just ignored.)

So if you wish to suppress any other input check that nothing is left in `@ARGV` after the library is done parsing it.

I use [List::Util](https://perldoc.perl.org/List::Util) to avoid checking individuall all variables but please do so if you want to return to the user a specific message for faulty input.

I made all options lower case since capitalization in the question isn't consistent.  Please adjust as needed.

---

<sup>†</sup>  Parsing input by hand places a lot of burden on the programmer.

We need to devise a system that seems suitable for our purpose (may be hard to tell ahead of time) -- how are options split from the command-line? what about multiple words, special chars etc? for which shell is this? order -- positional? (error prone and very hard to check!) etc.

Then we need to parse it, anticipate and catch all manner of possible errors, possibly introduce some post-processing.

A lot of work, debugging and testing, iterations ... and the result is most likely brittle, so that when there is a change to make in the future the rest (or all of it?) may need reworking.

That's what libraries are for; all that, and more, is done.

Answer (score 1):

Input data validation rarely can be achieved with simple regular expression in one step.

Please inspect the following demo code for possibility country/name to include spaces and dashes which suggested by you regular expression will not handle properly.

To avoid potential pitfalls do not use space as field separator -- names and countries possibly can include spaces/dashes -- use of `,` fills more natural.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $data;
my @header = split(/,/, <DATA>);

chomp @header;

while(my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp $line;
    my @read = split(/,/,$line);
    say "Warning: $line number of arguments is " . scalar @read
        unless @read == 5;
    $data->@{@header} = @read;
    $data->{$_} =~ /[^a-z -]+/i && say "Warning: '$_ => $data->{$_}' does not look right"
        for @header;
    say Dumper($data);
}

__DATA__
Country,Husband,wife,child,pet
Japan,ken,Annie,may,money
China,Sonny,Ae-Cha,Bora,coin,hummer
South Korea,Sonny2,Ae-Cha,Bora,coin
```

Output sample

```
$VAR1 = {
          'Husband' => 'ken',
          'pet' => 'money',
          'child' => 'may',
          'wife' => 'Annie',
          'Country' => 'Japan'
        };

Warning: China,Sonny,Ae-Cha,Bora,coin,hummer number of arguments is 6
$VAR1 = {
          'Husband' => 'Sonny',
          'pet' => 'coin',
          'child' => 'Bora',
          'wife' => 'Ae-Cha',
          'Country' => 'China'
        };

Warning: 'Husband => Sonny2' does not look right
$VAR1 = {
          'Husband' => 'Sonny2',
          'pet' => 'coin',
          'child' => 'Bora',
          'wife' => 'Ae-Cha',
          'Country' => 'South Korea'
        };
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have a category which may contain space, splitting a string on space is not a good method, like has been exemplified with "What if the country is South Korea?" Polar Bear in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73647817/725418) suggests using comma as a separator instead, which would allow South Korea. Other workarounds might include quoting words with spaces and using a module that can handle quoting, such as [`Text::ParseWords`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Text::ParseWords), which is a core module in Perl.

Using `Text::ParseWords`:

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use Text::ParseWords;

my $str = qq("South Korea" Ken Barbie Mario Fido);
my @data = quotewords(" ", 0, $str);
print Dumper \@data;
```

```
$VAR1 = [
          'South Korea',
          'Ken',
          'Barbie',
          'Mario',
          'Fido'
        ];
```

But the main issue of counting words I think is most suitably done by splitting the string on space and counting the resulting fields. You can do this with `quotewords` like above, and then insert a test such as:

```perl
if (@data == 5) {
    print "Correct number of args";
} elsif (@data < 5) {
    print "Too few args";
} # etc.....
```

You can also manually split the string:

```
my @data = split ' ', $str;
```

A simple way to count with a regex is to match what you want to match, then assign it to a scalar context, with a little Perl magic:

```
my $count = () = $str =~ /\S+/g;  # how many non-whitespace matches do we get?
```

The empty list `()` in the assignment will put the regex into list context and return the number of matches to the scalar to the left.

---

But I feel that using a single string data input is not the best way. If you have an exact number of inputs to get, why not get them individually?

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use feature 'say';

my %data;
my @inputs = qw(country husband wife child pet);

for my $input (@inputs) {
    print "Enter value for '$input': ";
    chomp($data{$input} = <>);
}
print Dumper \%data;
```

Output:

```
Enter value for 'country': Sweden
Enter value for 'husband': Bob
Enter value for 'wife': Barbie
Enter value for 'child': Baby
Enter value for 'pet': Fido
$VAR1 = {
          'child' => 'Baby',
          'country' => 'Sweden',
          'husband' => 'Bob',
          'pet' => 'Fido',
          'wife' => 'Barbie'
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `.`, which matches the spaces that separate words. Replacing it with what an answer consists of (for example letters, numbers, and dashes) would be better.

There might be a better solution but this is what I've come up with.

```
/^([\w\d-]+\s[\w\d-]+){4}$/
```

Comment: Note: separating answers by space might cause an issue when the answer must contain space, e.g. country == South Korea.

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong that at the beginning the first `.+` matches whole string `Japan ken Annie may money hank queen`, then give back 4 strings each matches code `\s(.+)`. So the result of your code is :

> Group 1 `Japan ken Annie`
>
> Group 2  `may`  `money`  `hank`  `queen`

You can fix it using `\w+` instead of `.+`.

Here is a demo: https://regex101.com/r/jQ8IE0/1